# How to connect an Alcatel-Lucent IP touch phone over VPN?

Tags: vpn, voip, alcatel-lucent

We have some workers working at home, and we thought about providing them IP phones (Alcatel-Lucent IP Touch) which they could plug into their computers through their Ethernet port (or an external USB dungle). Since they have access to a VPN, we're trying to configure the phones so they can connect through it, but we're stuck with the message "no tftp response".

We've tried setting static and dynamic IPs, nothing seems to work.

If we connect another computer (instead of the phone), then that computer gets an IP and can communite just fine with the network.

We've looked at various forums, but despite many having asked this question before, we find no resolution to the problem. (Did all those asking dropped the matter, or silently without the answer?)

Is this even feasable?

Answer (score 0):

The phone is trying to get a provision of some sort (config file/firmware upgrade/etc) using a TFTP server that is not present. If you run a Wireshark traffic capture you will surely see what file/s the phone is trying to TFTP retrieve.